# Почему метод insert класса SQLiteDatabase или SQLiteOpenHelper возвращает id = -1

Tags: android

Вообщем я просто начинающий разработчик и изучаю уроки, есть один в котором у меня возникла проблема, хотя все соблюдено, но урок стары, может уже со временем изменилось.
В строке long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv); 
мне возвращается id -1 всегда, хотя должны были просто добавляться в базу имя и эмайл и присваиваться автоматически id методом insert.

```
package ru.nkloony.sqlite;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLog";

    EditText etName, etMail;
    Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        etMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String mail = etMail.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Inserted in mytable");
                cv.put("name", name);
                cv.put("mail", mail);

                long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = "+ rowID);
                break;
            case R.id.btnRead:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Rows in mytable");

                Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
                    int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
                    int mailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("mail");

                    do {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ID = "+ c.getInt(idColIndex) +
                        ", name = " + c.getInt(nameColIndex) +
                        ", mail = " + c.getInt(mailColIndex));
                    }while(c.moveToNext());
                }else
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 rows");
                    c.close();
                    break;
            case R.id.btnClear:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "clear mytable");
                int delCol = db.delete("mytable", null, null);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted rows count = " + delCol);
                break;

            }
            dbHelper.close();

        }

    }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public DBHelper(Context context){
            super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d("myLog", "OnCreateDatabase");
            db.execSQL("create table mytable( " +
                    "id integer primary key autoincrement," +
                    "name text," +
                    "email text" + ");");
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 возвращается в случае если во время добавления в таблицу произошла ошибка. Можете заменить ```insert``` на ```insertOrThrow``` для получения стектрейса ошибки по которому можно будет понять что у вас не так.

Answer (score 3):

Решил свою проблему, просто изменив в этих строчках:

```
String ***mail*** = etMail.getText().toString();
cv.put("***mail***", ***mail***);
```

название mail на email:

```
String ***email*** = etMail.getText().toString();
cv.put("***email***", ***email***);
```

и все почему то начало работать.))

Comment: Ну видимо столбец в таблице называется ```email```, а не ```mail```. А вообще странно что вы угадываете название столбцов, ведь вы сами создавали БД и должны четко знать какие имена имеют столбцы в БД.